# Can't write and read to stdin/stdout using Python

Tags: php, python

I'm working in Python 2.7 on MacOS 10.7.4. This is part of a longer script (not written by me) that essentially gives PHP some configuration options, writing them to PHP's stdin and then reading them from its stdout.

In practice, I don't seem to be able to read from stdout at all. The script below should write 'hello world', but all it writes is a blank line.

Could anyone suggest what's going wrong? I'm not very familiar with the way that `stdin` and `stdout` work in Python, or with PHP at all, so I'm struggling to debug this.

```
php_path = '/usr/bin/php'
args = [php_path]
child = subprocess.Popen(args,
      stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
      universal_newlines=True)
# Write to PHP stdin
print >>child.stdin, """
<?php
print "hello world\n";
# In reality we'd write some configuration options here,
# but in practice we can't even write 'hello world'. 
}
?>"""
child.stdin.close()
# Read from PHP stdout
line = True
while line:
    print 'line', line
    line = child.stdout.readline()
    print 'line from stdout', line
    if line == "hello world\n":
        break
else:
    raise Exception, "%s: failed to read options" % (php_path)
```

The output from this is:

```
line True
line from stdout 

line 

line from stdout Parse error: parse error in - on line 5

line Parse error: parse error in - on line 5

line from stdout 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise Exception, "%s: failed to read options" % (php_path)
Exception: /usr/bin/php: failed to read options
```

There is definitely a PHP at `/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: You should use `Popen.communicate`, this is much simpler and automatically avoid deadlocks. The real problem is already pointed out in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're debugging the wrong thing. You send that string to PHP, and you're getting a PHP error back. PHP is complaining about a *parse error in - on line 5* to me.

Now - is a special filename meaning stdin, so it's complaining about the 5th line you sent it, which seems to be a dangling `}`.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an extra curly brace in the end of php script, that might cause the problem.